# Coin-Slider does not display buttons correctly (except in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Not sure why this is occurring, if I go to the coin-slider page in IE or Firefox the JavaScript works, but once I apply it to my local build for a site it displays the buttons as numbers and doesn't show the background box for the slider titles.

It works perfectly in Google Chrome though. I've triple checked my html and css and it looks correct, any ideas?

How it appears in [Chrome](http://oi42.tinypic.com/ap2ki.jpg), and how it appears in [IE/Firefox](http://oi42.tinypic.com/2vc6wcw.jpg) (Hovering over what should be the circles in the second image).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="coin-slider-styles.css">       
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="coin-slider">
        <a href="group.html">
            <img src="img/sliderGroup.jpg">
            <span>
                heading1 
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="plan.html">
            <img src="img/sliderPlan.jpg">
            <span>
                heading2
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="num.html" >
            <img src="img/sliderNum.jpg">
            <span>
                heading3
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="exp.html" >
            <img src="img/sliderExp.jpg">
            <span>
                heading4
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="rep.html">
            <img src="img/sliderRep.jpg">
            <span>
                heading5
            </span>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider({width:800, height:300,  spw: 12, sph: 5, sDelay: 1, delay: 6000, opacity:0.95, hoverPause: true, links: true, effect: 'rain' , titleSpeed: 500});
    });
</script>
</body>
```

```
.coin-slider { 
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    }

.coin-slider a{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    }

.cs-buttons {
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    }

.cs-buttons a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; 
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #B8C4CF;
    text-indent: -1000px;
    }

.cs-active {
    background-color: #454545;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

.cs-title {
    width: 780px; 
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #454545; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 13px;
    }

.cs-prev, .cs-next {
    background-color: #454545;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any 404's for missing media ? Can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Nope, no 404's - I have some temporary media for my local build. Here's a JFiddle from the post below, but that deosn't seem to work at all on my computer (lists all the images rather than displaying the slideshow.)

http://jsfiddle.net/sarath704/cgU9R/

Answer (score 0):

here it is working fine in
http://jsfiddle.net/sarath704/cgU9R/

check once where you get problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#coin-slider').coinslider({width:800, height:300,  spw: 12, sph: 5, sDelay: 1, delay: 6000, opacity:0.95, hoverPause: true, links: true, effect: 'rain' , titleSpeed: 500});
    });

</script>
<style>
.coin-slider { 
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    }

.coin-slider a{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    }

.cs-buttons {
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    }

.cs-buttons a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; 
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #B8C4CF;
    text-indent: -1000px;
    }

.cs-active {
    background-color: #454545;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="coin-slider">
        <a href="group.html">
           <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/games/mini_ninjas.jpg" alt="Mini Ninjas" />
            <span>
                heading1 
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="plan.html">
            <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/games/prince_of_persia.jpg" alt="Price of Persia" />
            <span>
                heading2
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="num.html" >
            <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/games/spiderman_shattered_dimensions.jpg" alt="Spiderman: Shattered Dimensions" />
            <span>
                heading3
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="exp.html" >
            <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/games/brink.jpg" alt="Brink" />
            <span>
                heading4
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="rep.html">
           <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/games/borderlands.jpg" alt="Borderlands" />
            <span>
                heading5
            </span>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the JFiddle, but it doesn't run on here, it displays the images in a list rather than a slideshow.

Comment: yeah, the slideshow works, however the background for the title doesn't show up, the font color is incorrect and the circles to represent the different slides show up as numbers the same color as the page background.